# Keys are not working in their proper manner

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I searched a lot on the internet and could not find anyone else with this problem.

My keyboards keys are not working correctly. I open the terminal and when I typed **D** on the keyboard it just beeps and nothing shows in the terminal, other keys have the same issue. **enter** Doesn't work. I reset the settings using *Screen keyboard* and writing `dconf reset -f /`. This doesn't doesn't work at all. No change. When I first open the laptop it shows 3-4 options. Ubuntu and Windows are two of them. I can not choose the OS as the "Up down" keys do not work. By and large I think something has changed my keys.

Apologies as I don't know how to write in this forum.

Thank you.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details, ie. are you using Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? what release of that product etc.  Have you tried replacing the keyboard with another, to ensure the issue isn't the hardware/keyboard itself?  Have you booted *live* media (ie. another OS on different media) to again test your hardware? or tested using `xev` or equivalent on a booted system?

Comment: This is ASUS Vivo book. Yes it is Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I have checked with external keyboard same thing goes on. Only the screen keyboard work. Unfortunately I can't switch to windows 10 as I was unable to scroll down, keys are not working. Sorry I don't know ```xev```.

Comment: If your notebook is one of those devices that allow the device to be flipped around to pretend it's a tablet, then you may need to check the switch *inside the case* that tells the hardware whether the machine is being used as a notebook or a tablet. Those things tend to fail pretty miserably after a few years of regular use, which results in what appears to be an unresponsive keyboard.

Comment: There is another thing to tell. It's all was going well. I was doing some python programming on jupyter lab making the full screen. I tried to write it fast. So I typed fast what I see and suddenly keys are slow down. And the above problem is occurred. Is their any possibility to turn something on while I was typing fast.?

Answer (score 0):

Even at boot time you can't use your keyboard ? => This is a hardware failure. or Maybe, one of the Ctrl, or Alt key is stuck pressed on.